# Problem with Json parser to Csv in Python

Tags: python, json, csv, ijson

I am trying to convert a large Json file (~100GB) into csv using the ijson library in Python. This is my code:

```
import ijson
import csv

input_file_path = 'path_to_json_file' #json file is in dump
output_file_path = 'path_to_the_csv_file.csv'

# List the fieldnames you want to include in the CSV file
desired_fieldnames = [
"col_1","col_2","col_3",...
]

# Buffer to store rows before writing to CSV
buffer_size = 1000000
rows_buffer = []

def write_buffer(writer, buffer):
    for row in buffer:
        writer.writerow(row)

with open(input_file_path, 'rb') as input_file, open(output_file_path, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as output_file:
    objects = ijson.items(input_file, 'rows.item.doc')
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=desired_fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for item in objects:
        # Create a new dictionary with only the desired fields
        filtered_item = {field: item.get(field, '') for field in desired_fieldnames}
        rows_buffer.append(filtered_item)

        if len(rows_buffer) >= buffer_size:
            write_buffer(writer, rows_buffer)
            rows_buffer = []

    # Write any remaining rows in the buffer
    if rows_buffer:
        write_buffer(writer, rows_buffer)
```

And it results in this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path_to_python_program", line 64, in <module>
    for item in objects:
ijson.common.IncompleteJSONError: parse error: unallowed token at this point in JSON text
          ~version":"sahdhdhash=="}},  ]}
                     (right here) ------^
```

Comment: is it possible your json is not valid? That error looks like an unescaped quote at first blush.

Comment: JSON doesn't allow `,` after the last element of an array or object.

Comment: @JonSG I suspect the ijson error message doesn't show the full string, just some of the most recent characters, so you can't see the opening quote.

Comment: OK, what's your question? That error message is telling you the JSON is failing to parse, so you have invalid JSON. The snippet it provides in the error message indeed shows invalid JSON.